# segmentation fault, Crashing the program after executing all lines of code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

In this program here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch = 'A';
    char* ptr = &ch;

    ptr[8] = 'B';
    printf("ptr[8] = %c\n", ptr[8]);

    *ptr = 'C';
    printf("*ptr = %c\n", *ptr);
}
```

The output:

```
ptr[8] = B
*ptr = C
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I supposed that the program should segfault at the line `ptr[8] = 'B';` and crash, but the program did execute all the lines of code in it and then crashed which is something I don't really get.

Shouldn't it crash at the line `ptr[8] = 'B';` and stop the execution there ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the program is not required to crash & burn every time you write a bug. It could as well pretend to work fine, and save the crashing & burning til another day. Like for example until after you've shipped 10000 units...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By writing into `ptr[8]`, you probably scribbled over the return address of whatever function called `main`, so the processor tried to jump to a weird place. Core didn't like it and took a huge dump.

Comment: Yes i know that, I just asked why it didn't crash at that line of code. It's not the invalid write that is causing the segfault, right ?

Comment: The write didn't trigger the segfault because it's an address on the stack. Thus the memory is available (and used by a stack frame)

Comment: @Rerito You clarified it well, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400535: file hello.c, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/sohil/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.c:5
5       char ch = 'A';
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400551 in main () at hello.c:9
9       printf("ptr[8] = %c\n", ptr[8]);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400551 in main () at hello.c:9
(gdb)
```

**You will never get seg fault on ptr[8] = 'C' as any invalid memory write , but when you access in printf then it will cause seg fault , as shown in gdb.**

Comment: That's under your system. Under 32-bit system the stack structure is different (and it's also affected by optimization/debug/instrumentation flags).

Comment: Plus, OP's output clearly shows a successful `printf()` :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to allocate some memory for the variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch = 'A';
    char *ptr;
    if (!( ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100)))
        return 1;

    ptr[7] = ch;
    printf("ptr[8] = %c\n", ptr[7]);

    ptr[8] = 'B';
    printf("ptr[8] = %c\n", ptr[8]);

    *ptr = 'C';
    printf("*ptr = %c\n", *ptr);

    printf("*ptr = %c\n", ptr[0]);

    free(ptr);
}
```